# Use AJAX in select form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm building a simple bug tracker tool.
I want to add AJAX.

When you've created a project, you can add a bug, you can give this bug a status (unsolved or solved).
I want to change this status with a button and using AJAX.

You can change the status trough this form:

```
    <form action="ajax/bugStatus.class.php" method="post">
          <label> Change Bug Status </label>
          <select name="status" id="status">
               <option value="Unsolved">Unsolved</option>
               <option value="Solved">Solved</option>
           </select>
           <input type='hidden' name='bugID' 
           value="
           <?php 
           $row = mysqli_fetch_array($bugres);             
           echo $row['id'];
           ?>
           "> 
           <input type='hidden' name='bugID' value="<?php echo $id;?>"> 
           <input name="btnChange" id="btnChange" class="small button" value="Change Status" type="submit"> 
    </form>
```

This is the bugStatus.class.php file:

```
 $status    = $_POST['status'];
 $bugID     = $_POST['bugID'];

 $sql=" UPDATE bugs SET status = '$status' where id = $bugID ";  

 $result = mysql_query($sql); 
 $result = mysql_real_escape_string($sql); 

 if($result){
      header('Location: ../bugpage.php?id='.$bugID); 
      } else { 
      echo "There is something wrong. Try again later."; } 
      mysql_close();
```

This is the app.Change.js file where AJAX is implemented:

```
            $("#btnChange").on("click",function(e){

    var update = $("#post").val();

    // AJAX CALL naar ajax/save_tweet.php
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/bugStatus.class.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {update : update}, 
    dataType: "json"
    });


    request.done(function(msg) {
    if(msg.status = "sucess")
    {
        // OK
        var select = update;
    }
    else
    {
        // NOT OK
    }
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });

    e.preventDefault(); 


});
```

What am I doing wrong, 'cause I doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no element with id=post, so `var update = $("#post").val();` will be blank.  Instead, you probably want to send the serialized form `$("form").serialize()`.

Second, you're not returning JSON in the Ajax handler, but plain text -- so, remove the `dataType: json` (either that or use JSON_encode to echo valid JSON).

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/bugStatus.class.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("form").serialize(),        // status=Unsolved&bugID=123
});
```

Third, there is a mistake in your form, you've got a duplicate `bugID` input (not sure if that would break it, though).

Fourth, you're not actually returning anything to the Ajax request on success?  It looks like you're expecting "success", in which case you'd want:

```
if($result){
    echo "success";      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ajax like that. You should use a example form 1st comment or you should in your data property set values like this data:{status:$("#status").val(),bugID:$("#bugID").val()},
if you use that remove dataType from ajax. In html you must to set id of hidden field to "bugID" and use it once.  And in php file you should remove this line of code "$result = mysql_real_escape_string($sql), because of that your $result will never be true.